# Comparing epoch dates in different formats for a specific time gap

Tags: bash, date, epoch

Capturing the last built date from Jenkins gives me an epoch date in the format `1493146210998`, whereas today's date is (roughly, at the time of writing) `1493146250`. Obviously they're in different units.

I need to check the two dates, and find out if "right now" is at least eight hours later than the jenkins timestamp. I think I'm correctly converting the first timestamp to match the units of the second (diving by 1000) but the math involved in comparing the two is tripping me up.

This will be in a bash script and will end up something like;

```
jenkinsBuild="1493146210998"
lastBuild=(`expr $jenkinsBuild / 1000`)
currentTime=(`date +%s`)

if( "$lastBuild" is less than eight hours before "$currentTime" ) {
        echo "Times are too close together."
    }
```

**How do I check if the two times are less than eight hours apart?** Feel free to substitute today's date if this gets answered more than eight hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bash` arithmetic operator `$((..))` in an `if-clause` as

```
jenkinsBuild="1493146210998"
if (( $(( ($(date +%s) - $(date -d@${jenkinsBuild:0:10} +%s))/(60*60) )) < 8 )); then
    echo "Times are too close together."
fi
```

The idea is to get the 10 digits from the `jenkinsBuild` variable and do the GNU date arithmetic to get the EPOCH value in hours and see if it is less then 8 to get the condition working.

---

Seems OP has the native `Mac OS X` version of `bash`, which does not have GNU toolkit and no GNU `date` command, so do the arithmetic as

```
jenkinsBuild="1493146210998"
if (( $(( ($(date +%s) - ${jenkinsBuild:0:10} )/(60*60) )) < 8 )); then
    echo "Times are too close together."
fi
```

Comment: not sure if typo or user error, but I'm getting `line 2: (1493148707 - )/(60*60) : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/(60*60) ")`

Comment: @Alex : it means you don't have the variable defined `jenkinsBuild` , as you claimed in the question. Define it and try it back

Comment: I copied your script character for character - even ran it with an `echo` to make sure. It must be failing in the if somehow but I'm not familiar enough with your code to know why

Comment: @Alex: What is the value of `jenkinsBuild`? can you print it? Also, can you run it with a `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of your script

Comment: adding the path and the line `echo $jenkinsBuild` - same error. Is it possible something you have isn't compatible with mac bash? I've had problems like that before

Comment: @Alex: Yes the date command in native Mac OS does not support -d flag in `date` command, do you have a machine with GNU toolkit?, check `date --version`, it probably reports a different version than `GNU`

Comment: @Alex: Try my most recent update on for the `date` version supported by your machine

Answer (score 0):

In `bash v4.4+` you can use pure bash, like:

```
jenkinsBuild="1493146210998"
diff=$(( $(printf "%(%s)T") - (jenkinsBuild/1000) ))

(( diff < 8*60*60 )) && echo "Too close" || echo "OK"

#or    
if (( diff < 8*60*60 )); then
        echo "Too close"
else
        echo OK
fi
```